# Javascript listener not firing if before end of jquery .slideDown() animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

simple one i hope!

The problem im having is that i have an ('itemID').mouseover, which fires a jquery slide-down animation for a menu box.
The problem is that if the mouse leaves the original item (in this case a text link) before the end of the slideDown() amination, the .mouseleave function is not called.

It works fine otherwise!!

This is what im using: (menu14 is the text link, FunctionsMenu3 is the hidden div containing the menu items)

```
$('#menu14').mouseover(function() {
   $('#FunctionsMenu3').slideDown('fast', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});

$('#FunctionsMenu3').mouseleave(function() {
   $('#FunctionsMenu3').slideUp('fast', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

It seem to me that the JS CANT be fired, because its busy doing the slide...
site can be seen at http://www.impero-classroom-management.com
thanks in advance!!

Comment: `mouseleave` is IE only (although this is fixed by jQuery). Have you tried using a `hover` construct yet? See: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

On mouseleave, try `.stop()` to cancel the current animation.

```
$('#menu14').hover(
  function() {
   $('#FunctionsMenu3').slideDown('fast');
  },
  function() {
   $('#FunctionsMenu3').stop().slideUp('fast');
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi Christoph!
Thats closer to what i want, it works 99% however, if i hover then leave quickly, the div will only slide next time to he height that it was cancelled at!! IE if i hoveredm then left when it had got, say half way down, it will close fully, but next time it will only drop to that level... How odd!

Comment: Have stop() on both functions

Answer (score 0):

Well i got around it in the end by not animating the drop down, only the slide up.

not a fix, but it was all i could really do!!

```
$('#FunctionsMenu5').mouseleave(function() {
   $('#FunctionsMenu5').slideUp('fast', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
$('#menu15').mouseover(function() {
   $('#FunctionsMenu5').show();
});
```